# strftime for Indonesia Locale

Tags: php, locale, strftime

I am using strftime function of php to get time according to my set locale. So for Indonesian in case of February it is returning 'Pebruari' instead of "Februari".

Suggest what to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');
echo strftime("Today in Indonesia is %B");
?>
```

This will return you "Februari"...

Comment: not working it gives me same … infact setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND'); is not changing the locale i guess….

Comment: If I am not wrong, it will not change if this Locate Support is not available by your provider...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Indonesian locale is not installed on the server you are working with.

If you have shell access to your server then can you kindly try:

```
locale -a
```

And check which locates are installed on your Server.

Comment: Yes, that means the Locate is available. But be sure from your Service Provider that whether the Locate is Enabled or not... They may not support it...